# Details on using MFSideMenu

Tags: ios, mfslidemenu

I'm trying to use the `MFSideMenu` to implement a facebook like sliding side menu. My problem is I keep getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS error=2` on this line in the `MFSideMenu` library:

```
256: closeSideMenuCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

Any ideas what that might be causing it? I have added the `QuartzCore.framework` and added the **ARC flag** to the `MFSideMenu` files.

**Update:**
I've went through the build settings of both my project and the demo project (which works fine) and I can't find any differences. The deployment target is 4.3 on both projects.

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure that you can target ios below 5.0 with MFSideMenu.

Comment: `MFSideMenu` supports iOS 4.3 upwards. I ditched that library and ended up using `ECSlidingViewController`, thanks though!